# DataContract and UserControl

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have a `LamFile` object that I want to serialize :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(WaypointsMap))]
public class LamFile
{
  public WaypointsMap WaypointMap;

  public LamFile(WaypointsMap w)
  {
    WaypointMap = w;
  }

  public string GetDataContractSerialization()
  {
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
    {
      DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LamFile));
      ser.WriteObject(s, this);
      s.Position = 0;
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
      return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}

[DataContract]
public enum WaypointsEditionMode { Add, Delete }


[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(WaypointsEditionMode))]
public sealed partial class WaypointsMap : UserControl
{
  [DataMember]
  public WaypointsEditionMode = WaypointsEditionMode.Add;
}
```

The problem is the call to `GetDataContractSerialization()` throw an `InvaliddataContractException`:

> Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

I have -as said in the exception description- mark the `UserControl` with the `DataContractAttribute` and mark the desired attribute with `DataMemberAttribute`

What is the problem ?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you're not using KnownTypeAttribute correctly.  In your case, you don't need it at all.

Comment: You can't serialize a UserControl.

Comment: Which one do I have to remove ? All of them ? Removing them doesn't solve the problem (and if I change the usercontrol class to a "normal" class, this works).

Comment: That's what it seems. That is the "Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute." part of the exception's description that troubles me.

Comment: You need to define your own data model and decorate it with the data contract attributes.  Don't try to use UserControl as a base class for your model.  If that doesn't make sense, I'd suggest you do some more research on Data Contracts as you may be missing some fundamentals.

Comment: You can't serialize the UI. Serialize your **Data** instead. If I got a cent every time I say this in SO, I'd be richer than Bill Gates by now.

Comment: Just note that I don't care about UI. I just want to serialize some properties (like the WaypointsEditionMode). The problem above is a -very- simplified version. Extract the DataModel from this particular UserControl would be very tricky. BTW, all my other object serializations are based on data and it works great.

Comment: `Extract the DataModel from this particular UserControl would be very tricky` - What do you mean? in XAML based technologies you should be using proper DataBinding, there's no such thing as "extract data from the UI"... please clarify.

Comment: I currently wrap a control (Bing Map) which precisely doesn't allow data binding (for performance reasons it seems).